# How to make sure binary file is not invalid when upload in iTunes connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, binaryfiles

How to make sure that when uploading binary file (ipa file after archiving) in iTunes Connect doesn't turns out invalid binary.

I just want to make sure and double check every thing that when i upload binary in iTunes Connect system won't say that binary is invalid.

What are the key point to check to make sure binary is valid.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode's window|organizer|archives has an option to validate an archive.

Comment: Thanks. I validated it and it says No identities are available for signing.